# Searching deeply nested object array for a single key

Tags: javascript, traversal

I am trying to search through a deeply nested array and find if a key exists anywhere inside. I have written up a piece of code which does the traversal, but because it is not recursive (only self calling) it cannot return whether or not it has found anything. It just returns `undefined` since it reaches the end of the function on one of passes.

I was wondering if there was a way I could do this which would allow me to return `true` on the first occurrence of a specific key.

Here is a JS bin of what I have been working with so far:

https://jsbin.com/qaxuwajuso/edit?js,console

And here is a direct paste of the code from the above example:

```
function traverse(item, key) {
    if (typeof item === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item) && item !== null) {
        // Object
        for (let itemKey in item) {
            if (itemKey === key) {
                // Is it possible to return true and break out of the function here?
                console.log('found the key: ' + itemKey + ' With value: ' + item[itemKey]);
            }

            traverse(item[itemKey], key);
        }
    } else if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        // Array
        for (let i = 0; i < item.length; ++i) {
            traverse(item[i], key);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is nothing like a JSON Array or a JSON Object. JSON is string base representation of data, that has to be parsed using `JSON.parse` before it can be traversed. What you assign to `data` is a regular Array.

Comment: Updated the title to signify that I am trying to traverse a object array instead of JSON. Thanks!

Comment: How is it not recursive?

Comment: Because it has a fall through when the data coming in is not a object or an array. My definition of recursive might be wrong through.

Comment: A recursive function is simply one that references *itself*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `for...in` and store result in one var and then check that var before you call function again and break loop if value is found.

```js
const data = [{"id":"2144d998-4c33-4b03-93d2-f6c675b24508","statePath":"div","props":{"className":"testing","name":[{"first":"John","last":{"statePath":"lastName","anArray":[{"anObject":{"anotherArray":[{"doesItWork":{"statePath":"hello"}}]}}]}},{"first":"Jane","last":{"statePath":"lastName"}}]},"children":"hi"}]

function traverse(item, key) {
  let result = false;

  for (var i in item) {
    if (i == key) {
      result = true;
      break;
    }
    if (typeof item[i] == 'object' && !result) {
      result = traverse(item[i], key)
    }
  }

  return result
}

console.log(traverse(data, 'statePath'))
```

Comment: Wow! Very clean solution! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Sure you just need to return a flag of some kind to trigger the loops to stop

```js
/*
 * I am trying to search the following json array for any occurance of the key "statePath".
 * In a perfect world I would be able to find the first occurance, and return true from the
 * function.
 *
 * The following data is not real, I was just trying to write as much nested stuff as possible
 * to test that it traverses as far as needed.
 */

const data = [
    {
        id: '2144d998-4c33-4b03-93d2-f6c675b24508',
        element: 'div',
        props: {
            className: 'testing',
            name: [
                {
                    first: 'John',
                    last: {
                        statePath: 'lastName',
                        anArray: [
                          {
                            anObject: {
                              anotherArray: [
                                {
                                  doesItWork: {
                                    statePath: 'hello',
                                  },
                                },
                              ],
                            },
                          },
                        ],
                    },
                },
                {
                    first: 'Jane',
                    last: {
                        statePath: 'lastName',
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        children: 'hi',
    },
];

function traverse(item, key) {
  if (typeof item === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item) && item !== null) {
    // Object
    for (let itemKey in item) {
      if (itemKey === key) {
        console.log('found the key: ' + itemKey + ' With value: ' + item[itemKey]);
        
        // not sure what you want the end "return" of the func to be, I'm returning the value.  You could return true here instead, you could return a reference to the parent object, lots of possibilities
        return item[itemKey];
      }
      var found = traverse(item[itemKey], key);
      if (found !== undefined) return found;
      // otherwise keep looking
    }
  } else if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    // Array
    for (let i = 0; i < item.length; ++i) {
      var found = traverse(item[i], key);
      if (found !== undefined) return found;
    }
  }
}

var value = traverse(data, 'statePath');
console.log("value is " + value);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you James for your great answer! This helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

My variant:

```js
const data = [{id: '2144d998-4c33-4b03-93d2-f6c675b24508', element: 'div', props: {className: 'testing', name: [{first: 'John', last: {statePath3: 'lastName', anArray: [{anObject: {anotherArray: [{doesItWork: {statePath1: 'hello',},},],},},],},}, {first: 'Jane', last: {statePath: 'lastName',},},],}, children: 'hi',},];

function traverse(data, find) {
  for (let k in data) {
    let deepHaveKey = typeof data[k] === 'object' && traverse(data[k], find)
    
    if (find === k || deepHaveKey)
      return true
  }
  
  return false
}

console.log(traverse(data, 'statePath')); // true
console.log(traverse(data, 'state')); // false
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ilya! I appreciate it!